# Clear list when page is loaded

Tags: flutter, dart

I got a page(SearchComparePage) that has a few listTiles with checkboxes. When the FloatingActionButton is pressed, it sends the "mockIdList" which is a list that gets things added to it when the checkboxes are checked. So my problem is that when I press the button and send the list to the other page and I move back to my SearchComparePage, then the mockIdList is still filled with the data from the checked boxes from earlier. Is it possible to somehow clear the mockIdList everytime the page is loaded?

Im sorry if my question is weird. I'm not good at asking questions.

```
class SearchComparePage extends StatefulWidget{
SearchComparePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

final String title;


_SearchState createState()=> _SearchState();
}
class _SearchState extends State<SearchComparePage> {



 List<String> mockIdList = [];

  String searchString;
  String name = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        //backgroundColor: Color(0xFF8BC34A),
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          //elevation: 0,
          title: Text("Enklere valg"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget> [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            searchString = value.toLowerCase();
                          });
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                          hintText: 'Søk etter produkt',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)

                          )
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                          stream:
                            (searchString == null || searchString.trim() == "")
                                ? Firestore.instance
                                    .collection('products')
                                    .snapshots()
                                : Firestore.instance
                                  .collection("products")
                                  .where("searchIndex",
                                      arrayContains: searchString)
                                  .snapshots(),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.hasError)
                                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                default:

                                  return new ListView(
                                    children: snapshot.data.documents
                                        .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                      return buildResultCard(context, document);
                                      }).toList(),
                                  );

                              }
                            }
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
          ],
        ),

        // Button that sends the information in mockIdList to the other page.
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add),onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CompareResultPage(idList: mockIdList,)),
              );
            },
        ),

      ),
    );
  }



  // Widget that builds the listtiles
  Widget buildResultCard(context, data) {
  bool _isChecked = false; 

    navigateToDetail(context, data) {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductPage(product_id: data['product_id'],)));
    }

    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, StateSetter setState) {
        return Center(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(data['product_image'] ?? ''),
            ),
            title: Text(data['product_maker'] ?? ''),
            subtitle: Text(data['product_name'] ?? ''),
            trailing: Checkbox(
                    value: _isChecked,
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      if (value == true) {
                        setState(() {
                          mockIdList.add(data['product_id']);
                          _isChecked = value;
                        });
                      }

                      if (value == false) {
                        setState(() {
                          mockIdList.remove(data['product_id']);
                          _isChecked = value;
                        });
                      }

                  },
                  ),
            onTap: () => navigateToDetail(context, data),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: you can wait for ```Navigator.push```. It completes when you pop from the previous controller. There you can do the reset logic.

Comment: Sry but could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return from your other view you'll want to reset your `mockIdList`

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => ProductPage(
      product_id: data['product_id'],
    ),
  ),
).then((_) => setState(() => mockIdList.clear())); // <----Add this line of code
```